# “Your system has run out of application memory.” Springboard leak?

Tags: macos, memory, memory-leak

I have a problem with system run out of application memory last days. All my applications are frozen after the system message, and the only way to work again is to make a cold reboot with button.

I didn't install any new software, and Springboard is acting like crazy (I think it's the main source of leak since I am able to force Springboard to quit in Activity Monitor and somehow I can use my Macbook Pro for a few minutes after that).

[image]

I have 360GB available on my system disk and 16GB RAM.
MacOS Sierra, 10.12.6.

Does anyone have this issue, and how did you solve it?

Comment: Have you attempted to reset your Mac's SMC, PRAM, or boot in Safe Mode?

Comment: not yet. it seems that I can successfully work for several hours after reboot, so I don't know how safe mode could help me here. I didn't know about resetting SMC and PRAM, thanks, but if it'd be much more simpler for me to solve this issue without such measures. Right now, I'm downloading High Sierra, maybe, it'd go away with upgrade.

Comment: It's a good idea to try macOS High Sierra. I suggest Safe Mode only because booting into Safe Mode on Mac clears some caches, which is helpful for troubleshooting issues even when you're not running in Safe Mode.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I've killed iOS Simulator (part of XCode bundle), and Springboard memory leak seems to disappear after that.

Comment: That's good to know. I expect Xcode 9.2 to release alongside macOS 10.13.2. Once Xcode 9.2 releases, I'd suggest you update and see if this issue persists.

Comment: Xcode 9.2 released today on the Mac App Store. Can you let me know if that update resolves the memory leak in Simulator?

Comment: I didn't try that yet, but 9.2 beta (9C34b) is working for me right now. Also, guys from StackOverflow said that it could be issue with simulators (so you have to delete damaged ones, and add them once again).